# google maps api v3 not showing markers

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

So here's my code...

First I check the database...

```
function buscarCoords(callback){
      var result = result;
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM monitoreo_actual', function(err, result){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        callback({result:result});
      });
}
```

Then I have a callback function that basically calls yet another function that will convert the data into a google maps latLng format (too many functions i know, i will fix that later)

```
database.buscarCoords(function(resultsObject){
    convert.ConvertFromGrdToGoogle(resultsObject.result);
});
```

inside the convert function i call another function that will save the array to a txt file

```
function ConvertFromGrdToGoogle(grd){
........
files.saveMonActual(JSON.stringify(arrCoords));
}
```

this is the function that saves to the file

```
var saveMonActual = function(grd){
  fs.writeFile("grd2google.txt", grd, 'UTF-8', function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("=> grd2google.txt actualizado con las coordenadas convertidas a Google");
    }
  });
}
```

an example of the output

```
"'2','10.1850','-68.334','4','10.1850','68.334','3','10.1853','-68.334','5','10.1853','-68.334'"
```

and last but not least i have a function to read the data and strip it from the unnecesary quotes and single quotes.

```
var readMonActual = function(){
  var coordsArray=fs.readFileSync("grd2google.txt", "utf8");
  var coordsArray=coordsArray.substring(1,coordsArray.length-1);
  var myCoords=[];
  data=coordsArray.split(',');
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i+=3){
    myCoords.push([
                    Number(String(data[i]).replace(/\'/g, "")),
                    Number(String(data[i+1]).replace(/\'/g, "")),
                    Number(String(data[i+2]).replace(/\'/g, ""))
                  ]);
  }
  return myCoords;
}
```

this would be the console.log of that function

```
[ [ 2, 10.185, -68.334 ],
  [ 4, 10.185, 68.334 ],
  [ 3, 10.1853, -68.334 ],
  [ 5, 10.1853, -68.334 ] ]
```

So i call that function from the initialize() in the google maps html file's  tag

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.191, -68.191),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
  var markers = readMonActual().myCoords;
  for(i=0; i<markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(Number(markers[i][1]), Number(markers[i][2]));
    //bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: position,
             map: map,
             title: String(markers[i][0])
             });
  }
}
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

this is one of the many ways i've tried to display the map markers but they still won't show. Some help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is call

```
var markers = readMonActual().myCoords;
```

It should be

```
var markers = readMonActual();
```

You are returning an array from function.

And definition of `marker` array is missing in front of `for` loop:

```
var marker = [];
```

Check [example at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/jifev/1/edit). Function `readMonActual()` is changed to just return proper result. I cannot test database part.

Comment: it still doesn't work. i thought i wasn't getting the locations so i tried creating a div to print the locations there but the div won't even appear. and alert doesn't bring up anything..

Comment: i see now. the problem is that i'm not importing the .js file right, and i'm trying but the debugger still says it can't find the file.
see, i'm using express framework for node. and inside of my project directory i have, among others, these folders:
-views (which is part of the framework).
-custom_modules (which i created).
i have to load a js file that is in the custom_modules folder, into the .html file which is in views. but this doesn't work.
<script type="text/javascript" src="../custom_modules/files.js"></script>

Comment: basically i need to call 'project/custom_modules/files.js' from 'project/views/map.html'